# gender values not display properly

Tags: jquery

I think the error is in line `var gender=$("input[name='gender']:radio").val();`

```
             <!doctype html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Untitled Document</title>
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script> 
                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                  `$` character is just a shortcut for `window.jQuery`.
                    $("#sub").click(function()
                    {
     /*fetch username 
password*/
                var u=  $("input:text").val();
                var pa=$("input:password").val();
                var courses=[];
                $.each($("input:checked"),function()
                {
                    courses.push($(this).val());
                });
               //fetching gender value
         var gender=$("input[name='gender']:radio").val();
                //gender value not display correctly
                $("p").html(**"Username**:"+*u*+"**Password:**"+pa+**"Course** **selected:**"+*courses.join(",")*+"**Gender**"+*gender*);
                    });
                });

                 </script>
                </head>

                <body>
                <form onsubmit="javascript:return false;">
                Username<input type ="text" name="uname" >
                Password<input type="password" name="pass" >
                Course:
                java<input type="checkbox" name="java" value="java">
                Php<input type="checkbox" name="php" value="php">
                .net<input type="checkbox" name=".net" value=".net">
                javascript<input type="checkbox" name="javascript" value="javascript">
                Gender:
                Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
                Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
                <button id="sub">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <p></p>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `:radio` instead of attribute selector

```
 var gender=$("input:radio:checked").val();
```

that is if you are sure you have only a single radio button.

For specific element:

```
 $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
```

Comment: no it is not working..when i selectedgender:female than it always show male..and it also show gender value in selected course also

Comment: updated try it out. Just want to make sure that the `$ character is just a shortcut for window.jQuery.`   should be commented.

Comment: yes i remove it from there but it from there but it show me an same error again.please send me the correct code

Comment: ok do one thing. check you console in chrome web developer tools and see if there is any error there

Comment: one issue is clear that it take gender whatever i selected..but now it also shows selected gender in selected course also     .i make this change                                   var gen=$("input[name='gender']:checked").val();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var gender=$("input[name=gender][type=radio]:checked").val();
```

Use `:checked` selector if you want the checked element.

Comment: again it shows the same error...show male when i select female and also shows gender value in selected courses also

Comment: @user4785724 try adding selector `:checked` as above.